# How to calculate complex exponential in shell script

Tags: shell

Can some one tell me what is wrong with this piece of code

```
read n 

for ((i=1;i<=n;i++))
  do 
   a= $((16/2**$((i-1))))

    for ((j=1;j<=a;j++))
      do 
        echo "1"
      done 

done
```

When I executed it , i got error line 5: 16: command not found.

Comment: I am suspecting I am doing something wrong while calculating a

Comment: @that_other_guy  OP does not have spaces around equals as the linked Q ---  correction  except at  a=